# Macbook Pro wifi won't work

Tags: wireless, broadcom, mac, macbook-pro

I opened xdiganose and it told me to go to http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#devicefirmware in order to download and install the wireless driver. I followed the instructions for Ubuntu and it aborted the installation saying something about an unsupported device (I should've saved the output, I'm using a late 2011 13" Macbook Pro.) Now when I try `sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer` I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
firmware-b43-installer is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 338 not upgraded.
```

What do I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you have the driver which is known to work with macbook pros. Since presumably your laptop is not connected to the internet, first you need to have it temporarily connected to the internet using USB.

If you have a mobile phone which you can use as a "persnoal hotspot" temporarily, then you may connect it to your laptop by USB to get connected to the internet temporarily and in a terminal, type:

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get install -y bcmwl-kernel-source`

Hopefully this will get your wifi up and running.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the firmware manually:

```
wget http://www.lwfinger.com/b43-firmware/broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2
tar xf broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter
sudo b43-fwcutter -w "/lib/firmware" broadcom-wl-5.100.138/linux/wl_apsta.o
```

Note that you should have kernel 3.2 or newer for the above to work. See http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/b43/ for more details.

In this case you don't need `firmware-b43-installer` and can safely remove it.