# Installing drivers for Ubuntu 12.04 on MacBook Pro 9,1 Mid 2012 15 inch

Tags: 12.04, macbook-pro

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my MacBook Pro 9,1 Mid 2012 non retina 15 inch. I installed the 4 drivers from this link https://launchpad.net/~mactel-support/+archive/ppa?field.series_filter=precise but still I can't get wireless or bluetooth to work. Even adaptive brightness I think isn't working. Can anyone suggest where to get the complete set of drivers?

P.s. Additional drivers says no proprietary devices found which is weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed the wireless drivers thanks to this question: [Macbook Pro wifi won't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166504/macbook-pro-wifi-wont-work)

Also, after upgrading to 12.10, much of it works out of the box. Still figuring out how to safely install NVIDIA's drivers. This link might help: http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/ubuntu-quetzal-nvidia.html